# How to use FontAwesome for elements other than <i>

Tags: html, font-awesome

I am trying to change an icon using only css, and I need the envelope to show up. I want to use FontAwesome. I've imported it in my style.css file:

```
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
```

I've tried this, but it didn't work, it shows only the square:

```
.element:before {
   content: "\f0e0";
   font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

Interestingly enough, if I try the same in [jsfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrpud8nt/), it works. It must be that some of the other styles in Divi Theme that I'm using are blocking it. 
How to get it done?

This is the exact code I am using on [my page](http://hub.preseli.me/ashsears/test/):

```
a[title=flikr]:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome !important;
  content: "\f0e0" !important;

}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are right, it's in this particular case that it's not working. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use FontAwesome icons on different elements, you need to make sure to include the class and data elements on said html elements

```
<div class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

The part that is generating your icon is the class `fa-envelope`, the class `fa` determines that it will be using the FontAwesome font family.

Here is an example that utilizes the icons on a couple different HTML elements: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2v6x29rt/)

---

So as we found out, you have the default font overwriting, here is how I would handle it:

```
/* Target all of your :before tags in this schema (ul li a :before) */
.et_pb_social_media_follow .et_pb_social_icon a:before{
    font-family: FontAwesome !important;
}

/* call your icons content style separately */
.et-social-flikr a.icon:before {
    content: "\e0a6" !important;
}
```

This should target all of those squares in your nav and set their fonts to FontAwesome, then your content style should add the icons in.

Comment: this is great, but I am trying to avoid jQuery here, and that is the only way I can change the code here to add a class and aria-hidden attribute in this case.

Comment: Hi @ivanacorovic I'm taking a look at your page, what is this font family for? `    font-family: "ETmodules" !important;`? This is on an element that should be set to `font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;`

Comment: It's a default font, but I didn't look right. You are right, it's a better selector for this element than the one I'm trying to use, and since they're both !important, mine doesn't get picked. Thank you! I must have been looking at this for too long.

Comment: @ivanacorovic I actually just got this to work in dev tools, updating my answer now.